# Flutter how to change font color of DropDownButton

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton

Im trying to change the font color of my DropdownButton in flutter right now its black and i want to change it to white is there any way to do this?

[image: DropDownButton]

Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the style argument. [heres the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)

```
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple)
```